# How to get OHLC candle values while looking at Heikin Ashi chart?

Tags: pine-script, trading

I am currently building an indicator and strategy that can use Heikin Ashi values for the indicators calculations while looking at other chart types. Using the following code I have imported HA values into the script and it works perfectly.

```
ha_open = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, open)
ha_high = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, high)
ha_low = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, low)
ha_close = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close)
```

I am now looking for a way to base the calculations on normal candlestick charts (OHLC) but while looking at other chart types. I cannot find any reference to such a function on the PS kodify site, but surely there must be one. Is there a way i can do this or is it impossible?

Its more complicated but maybe there is a way to extract the OHLC data from the heikin ashi values?

I have looked on SO and found a couple suggestions but when trying them i get errors, and i cant seem to get around them.

```
selected_interval = input(title="Interval", defval="D", type=resolution)
//selected_interval = tostring(interval)

actual_close = plot(security(syminfo.prefix + ":" + ticker, selected_interval, close)

line 50: Undeclared identifier 'resolution';
line 53: Undeclared identifier 'ticker';
line 53: Undeclared identifier 'selected_interval'
```

SOLUTION:---

I have found a way to get the real OHLC values while looking at HA charts. So now the indicator and strategy I am building can be vied on any chart type with a relevant time axis.

Here is the code to get the real OHLC inputs.

```
ticker      = tickerid(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker)
```

realOpen    = security(ticker, timeframe.period, open,   lookahead= barmerge.lookahead_on)
realHigh    = security(ticker, timeframe.period, high,   lookahead= barmerge.lookahead_on)
realLow     = security(ticker, timeframe.period, low,    lookahead= barmerge.lookahead_on)
realClose   = security(ticker, timeframe.period, close,  lookahead= barmerge.lookahead_on)

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the entire code please? That'll help identify the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, im new here so wasnt quite sure how in depth to go. I have fixed the problem now, will be uploading the whole thing soon. I will edit my post with the solution in case other people wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

I am also doing this in a strategy and I used the same code:

```
t = tickerid(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker)
realOpen = security(t, timeframe.period, open) 
realHigh = security(t, timeframe.period, high) 
realLow = security(t, timeframe.period, low) 
realClose = security(t, timeframe.period, close)
```

Just pass in the realClose or others to your calculations.  An additional note this only worked in Version 4 for me.